# How to use Java Regex to put a particular string into array?

Tags: java, regex

How can I put the  "no", "no", "0.002", "0.998" below into the String array with regex in Java?

```
 String lines = "     1       2:no       2:no       0.002,*0.998"
```

Could someone please tell me how to write "theRegex" below?

```
String[] matches = lines.split(theRegex); // => ["no", "no", "0.002", "0.998"]
```

In Python, it will be just one line:

```
matches = line =~ /\d:(\w+).*\d:(\w+).*\((\w+)\)/
```

But how about Java?

Comment: What are the rules for splitting exactly?

Answer (score 2):

`theRegex="[\\s,*]+"` (one or more spaces, commas or asterisk)

Input  `1 2:no 2:no 0.002,*0.998`
Output `["1","2:no","2:no","0.002","0.9"]`

**Edit**

> The input String is " 1 2:no 2:no 0.002,*0.998", and the expected output is ["no", "no", "0.002", "0.998"]

In that case it is not possible to use `split` alone, because for ignoring `1` you need to treat `\d` as a delimiter, but `\d` is also part of the data in `0.002`.

What you can do is:

```
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\d(?:$|:)");
   String[] matches = lines.trim().split("[\\s,*]+");
   List<String> output = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(matches));
   for (Iterator<String> it=output.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
     if (Pattern.matcher(it.next()).find()) it.remove();
   }
```

`find("^\\d(?:$|:")` matches strings of the form `digit` or `digit:whatever`. Note that the pattern is compiled once, then it is applied to the strings in the list. For each string one has to construct a matcher.

Comment: The it will become ["", "1", "2:no", "2:no", "0.002,*0.998"] but not ["no", "no", "0.002", "0.998"]. Also, something doesn't match above pattern will also get split but the space and being put into the array...

Comment: 1. Do `lines.trim().split(...)` if `lines` may begin with spaces. 2. Can you provide the counterexample and the expected output in that case?

Comment: The input String is "     1       2:no       2:no       0.002,*0.998", and the expected output is ["no", "no", "0.002", "0.998"] which is an array stores all this 4 elements. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks Javier, but the String type iterator doesn't have a function call "find"... would you please advise how can I use the find over there? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex...

```
(^\d|[\d]:|[\\s, *]+)+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "1       2:no       2:no       0.002,*0.998";
String[] arr = s.split(" +");
```

Comment: The it will become ["", "1", "2:no", "2:no", "0.002,*0.998"] but not ["no", "no", "0.002", "0.998"]. Also, something doesn't match above pattern will also get split but the space and being put into the array...

Comment: @Reimeus yes but before viewing expected answer.

Comment: @Kevin What is your condition for regex?

Comment: @AchintyaJha, I don't quite understand what do you mean condition... The input String is " 1 2:no 2:no 0.002,*0.998", and the expected output is ["no", "no", "0.002", "0.998"] which is an array stores all this 4 elements. Thanks!!